# A pair of words that mean fast- and slow- changing

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a pair of adjectives which mean, respectively:

- Fast/Frequently-changing
- Slow/Rarely-changing

**As an example usage:**

> Due to its everyday use, the balance of a current account can be quite *fast-changing*, but that of a savings account is more likely to be *slow-changing*.

And as a demonstrative graph: the value denoted by the red lines is more *fast-changing*, whereas the green value is a lot more *slow-changing*. The size of the changes is irrelevant - only the frequency is of importance.

[image: Fast and slow changing graphs]

The best I've come up with is *volatile* for the fast-changing part (probably closest to the third definition at [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/volatile)), but I can't think of a suitable antonym. To me, *stable* has more of a connotation of not changing very much when it does change, as opposed to not changing very often.

**By contrast:**

[image: Continuous graphs]

If the green and red graphs above are frequently and infrequently changing respectively, then the orange, blue and purple graphs are changing continuously (infinitely frequently) - they're all way off to the "frequently" end of the spectrum.

Comment: Is the amplitude of change relevant as well? It is possible to have hell of a wiggling function where values are barely changing.

Comment: @Arjang "The size of the changes is irrelevant - only the frequency is of importance.". Yes, a function which is constant for long periods before taking a massive jump to another value would be an example of "infrequently-changing". Likewise, a function which takes rapid, tiny steps would be a "frequently-changing" function.

Comment: Specifically in the example usage, you could write "due to its everyday use, the variability of the balance of a current account can be high, but that of a savings account is more likely to be low.

Comment: In a more technical context, suggested by the first graph given, you might refer to *pulse width*.

Answer (score 3):

For your example, 'dynamic' and 'static' work:

> **Example:** Due to its everyday use, the balance of a current account can be quite dynamic, but that of a savings account is more likely to be static.
>
> **dynamic**  adj.
>   ...
>   3. Characterized by much activity and vigor ....
>
> [dynamic. (n.d.) American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. (2011). Retrieved November 17 2015 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dynamic]
>
> **static** adj.
>   ...
>    3. showing little or no change ....
>
> [static. (n.d.) Random House Kernerman Webster’s College Dictionary. (2010). Retrieved November 17 2015 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/static]

Comment: I like dynamic, but I'm not quite so keen on static. Despite your given definition including "little ... change", if I saw something described as static, I wouldn't ever expect it to change.

Comment: @PhilipC, yeah, I was thinking I'd like to rephrase the example: "... is likely to be more static."

Comment: Idiommatically, I suppose the pair *active-idle* doesn't suit your context?

Comment: Yep, that'd make it easier. Unfortunately, I really could do with an absolute adjective, not a comparative one. And no, they're both active things, one just changes far more often than the other (like the bank accounts, or the values on the graph).

Comment: @PhilipC, along with *active-idle*, there's *active-quiescent*, *active-lethargic*. Other than *active*, *lively*, *vital*, *productive* are possible, each with their own oppositories.

Comment: @JEL I like "active-idle"...

Comment: @Elian, thanks--I also think it fits within the "*more likely* to be ..." phrasing context, but the OP ruled it out in a comment. Shucks.

Answer (score 1):

What about "stable" instead of "static"? I can see why "static" won't do - it usually implies that there is no change whatsoever - but "stable" often implies that change is possible.

So - "dynamic" and "stable".

Answer (score 0):

Abusing the term in mathematics :

[Smoothness and $C^k$ seem relevant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness).

for example : Smooth or bumpy function.

Comment: What I'm after isn't really related to the continuity of the value - in the question both graphs are discontinuous step functions. If we're heading into mathematics, I'm looking for a pair of words that, given two step functions, would differentiate between the one with few step discontinuities and the one with many (ideally considering the x-axis as time).

Comment: @PhilipC : yes, i know.However smooth function does conjure the image of not frequently changing, and bumpy function does. Hence misuse of mathematical term to fit something into everyday usage.

Answer (score 0):

There are great words here already for the quickly changing case.  Also you can say *up and down*.

For the slowly changing case: *boring, unchanging, steady, steady-going, slow moving.*

> Due to its everyday use, the balance of a current account can be quite **up and down**, but that of a savings account is more likely to be **slow moving**.

Answer (score -1):

We may use the terms "fluctuating-vs-consistent" in conformity with your example usage.

Comment: That would be for a different situation where some values are fluctuating and other values are constant. In the OP's situation, all the values are fluctuating.

Comment: Sorry for the spelling mistake. "Consistent" holds a balanced sense of variance as well.